# ArcGIS Online: Adding Screenshots to my content items

Tags: arcgis-online

Within ArcGIS Online, is it possible to associate an array of screenshots with a content item?

I see a property in the ArcGiS Online Search API response that includes "screenshots":[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is only available through Esri Market Place.  I had a separate question about the largeThumbnail field whose respondent explained:
[Populating Arcgis.com Large Thumbnail Field](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86548/populating-arcgis-com-large-thumbnail-field)